# bash awk search function

Tags: bash, awk

I have been trying for hours on a certain parts of my program, I will be greatful if someone can help me. I still cannot solve the problem of adding a new line called "Book is not found" at the bottom when 0 record is found, how do i do that? How do i make the search to be case insensitive also?

```
 awk  -F':' -v search="$title" '{ if($1 == search) {printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; i++ } else {printf "Book not found"} }END {printf "%d records found\n", i}' BookDB.txt
```

This give me things like

```
Title:dwaf
Author:
Book not found  
Book not found 
Book not found
Total, 0 record found
```

instead of

```
Title:wdawd
Author:





Book not found
Total, 0 record found

 If a record exist, it will show 
    Book not found
    Book not found
    Book not found
    Book not found
    Happy Day book
    Happy Day book
    Happy Day book
    Book not found
    3 records found

    instead of 
    Happy Day book
    Happy Day book
    Happy Day book
    3 records found
```

This does not show the "book not found" message

```
 if [ "$title" != "" ] && [ "$author" = "" ] ; then  
 awk  -F':' -v search="$title" '{ if($1 == search) {printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; i++ } else {printf "Book not found"} }END {printf "%d records found\n", i}' BookDB.txt 
 if [ "$i" < 1 ]; then
 echo -n "Book not found"
 fi
```

Next i have a error of case insensitive
i try to change the code

```
    awk  -F':' -v search="$title" 'IGNORECASE = 1;/^search/;'

  BEGIN { i=0; }

  {
    if($1 == search) {
      printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
      i++
    }
  }

  END {
    if(i >= 1) {
      printf "%d records found\n", i
    } else {
      printf "Book not found\n"
    }
  }' BookDB.txt
```

Comment: You want to print that message from the `END` block in awk if no entries have been found not in an `else` on the if/match.

Comment: Where are you setting `i` in your shell code?

Comment: ...and that's the thing -- you aren't. `i` is set only in awk, not in the outer shell.

Comment: the i is to be use as a counter, cause my text file have many line

Comment: Yes, but it's an **awk** counter, not a **shell** counter. Awk is not part of bash, and bash has no idea what awk variables are any more than it knows what variables you set in a Python or Perl program you run from bash are.

Comment: For the same reason, tagging these questions bash is silly -- the logic is all in awk, which is a completely different, unrelated language. You wouldn't tag a Python question "bash" just because bash is the shell you're starting the Python interpreter from, would you?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me out, i am really new to shell scripting. I am sorry for the confusion cause.

Comment: Once again: Awk scripting is not shell scripting; it's different from shell scripting in the same way that Perl scripting is different from shell scripting, even though people often use perl from a shell.

Answer (score 0):

`i` isn't a shell variable; it's only an awk variable. Thus, you can only reference it inside of `awk` code (and in the same instance of awk in which it was set).

Consider the following:

```
awk  -F':' -v search="$title" '

  BEGIN { i=0; }

  {
    if($1 == search) {
      printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
      i++
    }
  }

  END {
    if(i >= 1) {
      printf "%d records found\n", i
    } else {
      printf "Book not found\n"
    }
  }' BookDB.txt
```

---

Now, if you wanted to do this in bash, instead of awk, I might write it like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^-- must be /bin/bash, not /bin/sh

title=$1 # or get it from somewhere else, but needs to be assigned

i=0
while IFS=: read -r -a fields; do
  if [[ ${fields[0]} = "$title" ]]; then
    IFS=,; printf '%s\n' "${fields[*]}"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
  fi
done <BookDB.txt

if (( i > 0 )); then
  echo "$i books found" >&2
else
  echo "Book not found" >&2
fi
```

For case-insensitivity, I'd change the bash version like so:

```
title=${1,,} # store title in lower-case

# ...and lower-case the first field when comparing it.
if [[ ${fields[0],,} = "$title" ]]; then
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really learn a lot. I didnt know i ++ in awk is  i=$(( i + 1 ))

Comment: You can also write it as `(( i++ ))` in bash, but `i=$(( i + 1 ))` is the POSIX-compliant syntax.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to make it case insenstivite, may i know what went wrong here?
 `awk  -F':' -v search="$title" '
    BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1}/"$search"/ { i=0; }`

Comment: Couldn't say. I know bash quite well, but my awk is only passable. (Extended the answer with some notes on making the bash version case-insensitive, though; note that `${foo,,}` to expand to a lower-case version of `$foo` requires bash 4.x).

Comment: ...actually, IGNORECASE isn't part of POSIX awk at all. I don't suppose you might have been reading GNU documentation?

Comment: I'd consider `if (tolower($1) == tolower(search))` to make the awk version case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank for your help, i will read up and figure it. I was reading this regarding to case insensitive 
http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/01/make-awk-command-case-insensitive.html

Comment: Gotta' be careful about people blogging about things that work on their OS but don't work everywhere. That requires GNU awk, so it very certainly won't work on, say, MacOS (where Apple ships a BSD awk).